# Java : TCP client based on completable future unexpected behaviour

Tags: java, tcp, completable-future

I'm trying to get a TCP echo client work based on completable future chain approach. Here is my client code :

```
package tcp;

import utilities.CompletableFutureFactory;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.AsynchronousSocketChannel;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ClientTxRx {
    final private AsynchronousSocketChannel m_sockChannel;
    final private InetSocketAddress m_socketAddress;
    final private int m_dataBlockSizeInBytes;

    public ClientTxRx( String host, int port, int dataBlockSizeInBytes ) throws IOException {
        //create a socket channel
        m_sockChannel = AsynchronousSocketChannel.open();
        m_socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(host, port);
        m_dataBlockSizeInBytes = dataBlockSizeInBytes;
    }

    public void sendRequestReceiveResponse() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(m_dataBlockSizeInBytes);

        CompletableFutureFactory.create(m_sockChannel.connect(m_socketAddress))
        .thenCompose(s -> {
            System.out.println("client: start writing");
            buf.put(0, (byte)1);
            buf.put(1, (byte)2);

            return CompletableFutureFactory.create(m_sockChannel.write(buf));
        }).thenCompose(s -> {
            System.out.println("client: finished writing, start reading");
            return CompletableFutureFactory.create(m_sockChannel.read(buf));
        }).thenRun(() -> {
            final int test0 = buf.get(0);
            final int test1 = buf.get(1);

            System.out.println(String.format("client Data: %d %d\n", test0, test1));

            System.out.println("client: finished!");
        }).orTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).get();
    }
}
```

The problem I see is that socket read happens just immediately after socket write happens and no Data from server is actually awaited.

Here is a corresponsding server code :

```
package tcp;

import utilities.CompletableFutureFactory;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.AsynchronousServerSocketChannel;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ServerRxTx {
    final private AsynchronousServerSocketChannel m_serverSock;
    final private int m_dataBlockSizeInBytes;

    public ServerRxTx(String bindAddr,
                      int bindPort,
                      int dataBlockSizeInBytes) throws IOException {
        InetSocketAddress sockAddr = new InetSocketAddress(bindAddr, bindPort);

        m_serverSock = AsynchronousServerSocketChannel.open().bind(sockAddr);
        m_dataBlockSizeInBytes = dataBlockSizeInBytes;
    }

    public void startRxTx() {
        final ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(m_dataBlockSizeInBytes);

        CompletableFutureFactory.create(m_serverSock.accept())
                .thenAccept(s -> {
                    System.out.println("server: accepted");
                    try {
                        CompletableFutureFactory
                                .create(s.read(buf))
                                .thenCompose(readBytes -> {
                                    System.out.println("server: read passed, ready to write");
                                    final int test0 = buf.get(0);
                                    final int test1 = buf.get(1);

                                    System.out.println(String.format("server Data: %d %d\n", test0, test1));

                                    if (readBytes == -1) {
                                        throw new RuntimeException();
                                    }
                                    try {
                                        Thread.sleep(2_000);
                                    }catch (Exception e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                    buf.put(0, (byte)10);
                                    buf.put(1, (byte)20);

                                    return CompletableFutureFactory.create(
                                            s.write(buf)
                                    );

//                                    return CompletableFutureFactory.create(
//                                            s.write(executer.execute(buf))
//                                    );
                                }).orTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).get();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
                    }
                }).thenRun(() -> {
                    System.out.println("server: finished");
                }).orTimeout(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public void stopRxTx() {
        try {
            m_serverSock.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is auxiliary code to convert future to completable future I use :

```
package utilities;

import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class CompletableFutureFactory {
    public static <T> CompletableFuture<T> create(Future<T> future) {
        if (future.isDone())
            return transformDoneFuture(future);
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                if (!future.isDone())
                    awaitFutureIsDoneInForkJoinPool(future);
                return future.get();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // Normally, this should never happen inside ForkJoinPool
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                // Add the following statement if the future doesn't have side effects
                // future.cancel(true);
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        });
    }

    private static <T> CompletableFuture<T> transformDoneFuture(Future<T> future) {
        CompletableFuture<T> cf = new CompletableFuture<>();
        T result;
        try {
            result = future.get();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            cf.completeExceptionally(ex);
            return cf;
        }
        cf.complete(result);
        return cf;
    }

    private static void awaitFutureIsDoneInForkJoinPool(Future<?> future)
            throws InterruptedException {
        ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(new ForkJoinPool.ManagedBlocker() {
            @Override public boolean block() throws InterruptedException {
                try {
                    future.get();
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
                return true;
            }
            @Override public boolean isReleasable() {
                return future.isDone();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And a short test scenario :

```
import tcp.ClientTxRx;
import tcp.ServerRxTx;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            final var server = new ServerRxTx("127.0.0.1", 10000, 256);
            final var client = new ClientTxRx("127.0.0.1", 10000, 256);

            server.startRxTx();
            client.sendRequestReceiveResponse();
            server.stopRxTx();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5_000);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems I've found a solution - if we utilize a common ByteBuffer for read/write we must use flip() method. So the final solution would be as follows :

```
package tcp;

import utilities.CompletableFutureFactory;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.AsynchronousSocketChannel;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

public class ClientTxRx {
    final private AsynchronousSocketChannel m_sockChannel;
    final private InetSocketAddress m_socketAddress;
    final ByteBuffer m_dataBuffer;

    public ClientTxRx( String host, int port, int dataBlockSizeInBytes ) throws IOException {
        m_sockChannel = AsynchronousSocketChannel.open();
        m_socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(host, port);
        m_dataBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(dataBlockSizeInBytes);
    }

    public void sendRequestReceiveResponse() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
        CompletableFutureFactory.create(m_sockChannel.connect(m_socketAddress))
        .thenCompose(s -> {
            return CompletableFutureFactory.create(m_sockChannel.write(m_dataBuffer));
        }).thenCompose(s -> {
            m_dataBuffer.flip();
            return CompletableFutureFactory.create(m_sockChannel.read(m_dataBuffer));
        }).thenRun(() -> {
        }).orTimeout(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS).get();
    }
}
```